# innerHTML, <form> and Firefox

Tags: javascript, forms, innerhtml

I have a problem with Firefox. What I did works fine with IE but not with Firefox.

I use `innerHTML` to put a `div` with a form in a `window.parent`:

```
  window.parent.getElementById('DIV_page').innerHTML = getElementById('DIV_page').innerHTML ;
```

In this `div` the `form` looks like:

```
<form method="post" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;" name="f_bg_page" id="f_bg_page" target="If_menulb" action="if_menulb.php">
<input type="hidden" name="p" value="455">
<input type="hidden" name="w" value="prefs_lb">
```

How can I `innerHTML` a `div` with a form to `window.parent` ?

Edit:
They have the same ID but one is in the main page, the other is in an iframe, so they are not the same. I have found a way:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('DIV_page').innerHTML = '' ;
window.parent.document.getElementById('DIV_page').appendChild(document.getElemen‌​tById('DIV_page'));
```

but there is a but with IE and Opera, a `<input type="text">` in this form has a background white with color text in white, so we can't see the text in this `<input>`

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same ID on the same page. It may be that

Comment: @Pekka: You can but of course you shouldn't.

Comment: What JavaScript errors are you getting?

Comment: window.parent means your javascript code is inside an iframe? Is the parent window and iframe belongs to the same domain? if those two doesn't belong to the same domain, may be that is the problem. don't you need "document.getElementById("div_page").innerHTML" instead of "getElementById("div_page").innerHTML"?

Comment: You can use Firebug firefox extension to see is there any error showing in its Error Console. It will help you to find the exact cause of the error.

Comment: `getElementById` is a method of the `document` object - try `document.getElementById`. It could be that IE does some crazy global mapping for it (although I thought it did that only for elements in the DOM with an `id`)

Answer (score 0):

Pekka's comment is correct in this case. Because you have two elements with the same id, javascript doesn't kmow which one to choose. I imagine that this case is implemented in different ways in each browser. Some will sekect the first it finds, others will do something else.

Give the elements in question different id's and you'll find your problem is solved.

Comment: They have the same ID but one is in the main page, the other is in an iframe, so they are not the same. I have found a way: `window.parent.document.getElementById('DIV_page').innerHTML = '' ; window.parent.document.getElementById('DIV_page').appendChild(document.getElementById('DIV_page'));`, but there is a but with IE and Opera, a <input type="text" is white with color text in white !

Comment: Your javascript is still expected to tell the difference between two elements with the same id. It can nver work reliably.